# Minio Tenant is just stuck at "Waiting for Pods to be Ready" but the pod's status is Running

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minio

This is the config file I used for the Tenant

```
apiVersion: minio.min.io/v2
kind: Tenant
metadata:
  name: minio
  labels:
    app: minio
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/path: /minio/prometheus/metrics
    prometheus.io/port: "9000"
    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
spec:
  image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2021-04-27T23-46-03Z.release.0033eb96
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  credsSecret:
    name: minio-creds-secret
  pools:
    - servers: 1
      volumesPerServer: 4
      volumeClaimTemplate:
        metadata:
          name: data
        spec:
          accessModes:
            - ReadWriteMany
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 10Gi
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        runAsGroup: 1000
        runAsNonRoot: true
        fsGroup: 1000
  mountPath: /export
  requestAutoCert: false
  s3:
    bucketDNS: false
  certConfig:
    commonName: ""
    organizationName: []
    dnsNames: []
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  serviceMetadata:
    minioServiceLabels:
      label: minio-svc
    minioServiceAnnotations:
      v2.min.io: minio-svc
    consoleServiceLabels:
      label: console-svc
    consoleServiceAnnotations:
      v2.min.io: console-svc
  console:
    image: minio/console:v0.6.8
    replicas: 2
    consoleSecret:
      name: console-secret
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 1000
      runAsGroup: 2000
      runAsNonRoot: true
      fsGroup: 2000
```

When I apply the config file, the tenant is created but it keeps **waiting for pods to be ready**, meanwhile, the pod is **running** and is ready.

In the k8s Dashboard, when I inspect the pod I get this warning.

```
0/1 nodes are available: 1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.
```

Comment: Please share results of `kubectl get pods` filtered by minio pods and `kubectl describe pod` for all minio pods

Comment: @whites11 https://pastebin.com/raw/ARY7z06F

Comment: The minio container is in error state. You need to check the logs

Answer (score 1):

According to [Create a MinIO Tenant](https://github.com/minio/operator/blob/master/README.md#create-a-minio-tenant) and [Deploy a MinIO Tenant](https://docs.min.io/minio/k8s/tutorials/deploy-minio-tenant.html#b-create-the-required-persistent-volumes), if I understood correctly  you had to create PV on your own: [Local Persistent Volumes](https://github.com/minio/operator/blob/master/README.md#local-persistent-volumes)

> MinIO automatically creates Persistent Volume Claims (PVC) as part of
> Tenant creation. **Ensure the cluster has at least one Persistent Volume
> for each PVC MinIO requests**.
>
> You can estimate the number of PVC by multiplying the number of minio
> server pods in the Tenant by the number of drives per node. For
> example, a 4-node Tenant with 4 drives per node requires 16 PVC and
> therefore 16 PV.
>
> MinIO strongly recommends using the following CSI drivers for creating
> local PV to ensure best object storage performance:
>
> - Local Persistent Volume
> - OpenEBS Local PV

Have you did that? Can you please describe your pv and pvc? feel free to correct me

Answer (score 0):

you had to define storage class in yaml to bind the pv

Comment: Hi Afsar. Do you know what Storage Class is the user using? Because I think the error is so broad that  may worth ask the user about the SC and maybe PV and PVC yamls. Your answer may not be correct.